# matrix powers null space and range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a (singular) square matrix $A$, let $R(A)$ denote the range of and $N(A)$ the null space of $A$. Let $k$ be the least natural number such that $N(A^k)\cap R(A^k)=\{0\}$. Prove $k$ is also the least natural number such that $N(A^k)=N(A^{k+1})$ and $R(A^k)=R(A^{k+1})$ or simply
$$N(A^k)\cap R(A^k)=\{0\} \implies N(A^k)=N(A^{k+1}) \wedge R(A^k)=R(A^{k+1}).$$
Please do **not** resort to the Jordan canonical form. Rather this is to serve as a precursor to the construction of the Jordan canonical form.

---

Note: Take as given that $$N(A^k)=N(A^{k+1}) \vee R(A^k)=R(A^{k+1}) \implies N(A^k)\cap R(A^k)=\{0\}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We prove that the following three statements are equivalent for $k \geqslant 1$:

1. $N(A^k) \subsetneq N(A^{k+1})$
2. $N(A^k) \cap R(A^k) \neq 0$
3. $R(A^k) \supsetneq R(A^{k+1})$

$1. \Rightarrow 2.$: Pick $u \in N(A^{k+1}) - N(A^k)$. Show that $A^ku \in N(A^k) \cap R(A^k)$ is non-zero.

$2. \Rightarrow 3.$: Prove that the restriction of $A^k$ to $R(A^k)$ is a well-defined linear transformation with range $R(A^{k+k})$. Show that $A^k$ (and consequently $A$) restricted to $R(A^k)$ is singular. Conclude that the range of $A$ is a proper subspace using rank-nullity.

$3. \Rightarrow 1.$: Use Rank-Nullity.

Comment: $(2)\nRightarrow (3)$ since lhs of $(2) \supset$ lhs of (3).

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Fixed it now.

Comment: $(1)\implies (2)$  is enough to prove the desired result. But $(2)\nRightarrow (3)$. (1), (2) and (4) are equivalent.

Comment: Haha, my bad! Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: Should $(2)\implies(3)$ rather be the following? Prove that the restriction of $A^k$ to $R(A^k)$ is a well-defined linear transformation with range $R(A^{k+k})$. Show that $A^k$ (and consequently $A$) is singular.

Comment: Not exactly I guess. The reason to include the first sentence is to show that the range of the restricted action is smaller. The second line does follow from the action of $A^k$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150878/discussion-between-hans-and-haran).